# uninitialized constant Post::FriendlyID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

**Update**

A solution was found while writing this question. Still posting the question in case someone else has the same issue. My solution was because of a typo. See bottom of this post and the posted answer for complete code.

**Original Question**

Trying to implement the [friendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem in a RoR webapp.

I have already asked this question on the [GitHub forum](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/426), but saw in the Wiki notes to post my question here. I did do a search for an answer already and tried multiple suggestions, and nothing worked. Here is what I did.

**STEPS**

Worked ~~> Added `gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'` to my Gemfile and ran `bundle install`
Worked ~~> ran `rails g friendly_id`

```
$ rails g friendly_id
  create  db/migrate/20180404164213_create_friendly_id_slugs.rb
  create  config/initializers/friendly_id.rb
```

Fixed Migration File ~~> Changed `class AddSlugToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration` to `class AddSlugToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]`

Worked ~~> ran `rake db:migrate`

```
$ rake db:migrate
== 20180404164213 CreateFriendlyIdSlugs: migrating ============================
-- create_table(:friendly_id_slugs)
   -> 0.0246s
-- add_index(:friendly_id_slugs, :sluggable_id)
   -> 0.0048s
-- add_index(:friendly_id_slugs, [:slug, :sluggable_type])
   -> 0.0035s
-- add_index(:friendly_id_slugs, [:slug, :sluggable_type, :scope], {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0031s
-- add_index(:friendly_id_slugs, :sluggable_type)
   -> 0.0029s
== 20180404164213 CreateFriendlyIdSlugs: migrated (0.0392s) ===================
```

Worked ~~> ran `rails g migration add_slug_to_posts slug:string:uniq` and then ran `rake db:migrate`

```
$ rails g migration add_slug_to_posts slug:string:uniq
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20180404164731_add_slug_to_posts.rb
$ rake db:migrate
== 20180404164731 AddSlugToPosts: migrating ===================================
-- add_column(:posts, :slug, :string)
   -> 0.0078s
-- add_index(:posts, :slug, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0042s
== 20180404164731 AddSlugToPosts: migrated (0.0123s) ==========================
```

Updated `posts_controller.rb` ~~> 
From:

```
def set_post
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

To:

```
def set_post
   @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

Updated `post.rb` ~~> 
From:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :member

  Status = ['Draft', 'Under Review', 'Edits Needed', 'Completed']

  validates_with FeaturedValidator
end
```

To:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyID
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :member

  Status = ['Draft', 'Under Review', 'Edits Needed', 'Completed']

  validates_with FeaturedValidator
end
```

ERROR ~~> ran `rails c` to open the console to update previous posts to have a slug. ran `Post.find_each(&:save)` and got this error.

```
2.5.0 :001 > Post.find_each(&:save)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from (irb):1
        2: from app/models/post.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from app/models/post.rb:8:in `<class:Post>'
NameError (uninitialized constant Post::FriendlyID)
```

Researched and quit console and tried `spring stop` and the result stated that spring wasn't running. I then I tried the following and restarted the console each time before trying `Post.find_each(&:save)`

I tried changing `extend FriendlyID` to `extend ::FriendlyID`.

**ERROR**: `NameError (uninitialized constant FriendlyID)`

I tried adding `require "friendly_id"` at the beginning.

**ERROR**: `NameError (uninitialized constant Post::FriendlyID)`

And I tried both together.

**ERROR**: `NameError (uninitialized constant FriendlyID)`

I then saw somewhere that the `require: "friendly_id"` is supposed to be in the Gemfile and not the model. So, I deleted it there and added it to the Gemfile like so: `gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0', require: "friendly_id"`

**ERROR**: `NameError (uninitialized constant Post::FriendlyID)`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

***Solution***

As I was writing this out and looking at my code, I realized that my error was due to a typo. I typed `extend FriendlyID` instead of `extend FriendlyId`. Notice the final 'd' is suppose to be lowercase, not uppercase. I will post an answer with my final code that works for anyone else that is having this issue.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned at the end of my question. My issue was that I had a typo when calling to extend 'FriendlyId' in my model. I capitalized the final 'd'. Here is my final code that works.

Gemfile

```
# Friendly URLs
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0', require: "friendly_id"
```

app/models/post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :member

  Status = ['Draft', 'Under Review', 'Edits Needed', 'Completed']

  validates_with FeaturedValidator
end
```

app/controllers/post_controller.rb ~~ Changed `def set_post` to

```
def set_post
  @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```